# remember to be positive about reminding to check accepted answer

Tags: feature-request

Great to see that now, as opposed to a month ago, when I up vote an answer I like to a question that I asked, that it reminds me I can also mark the check mark to say it's the answer I accept. But could we have it say "remember" instead of "don't forget"? It has been shown that negative words at the beginning of commands are often ignored. E.g. better to tell a child "stop!" then "don't run into the street".

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23321/is-it-appropriate-to-comment-on-peoples-accept-rate