# What will happen with 0% accept rate?

Tags: discussion, accept-rate

What will happen to your account if you have a 0% accept rate?

or

How many questions that I did not accept for me to have a 0% accept rate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nothing will happen to your account. You may get people pestering you when you ask more questions, but you're not *required* to accept any answers.

Comment: And it is - at least in a rather [well-linked question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23321/is-it-appropriate-to-comment-on-peoples-accept-rate) on meta - considered non-constructive to comment on someone's accept rate. Questions should stand on their own merit, not the merits of the asker.